# How to export existing azure functions to vs code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

I want to edit functions on vsCode which I created on Azure by web browser.But I just can find some way to create new function on vsCode.Can anyone tell me how to export existing functions to vs code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Azure Function extension for VSCode?
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions

It allows you to see and edit function directly from VSCode however, you don't get the ability to make GUI mode changes, you will be making changes to core code component directly.